# Subquery using min function in sql

Tags: sql, subquery, min

Here is the schema

- author (aID, fName, surname)
- book (isbn, title, authorID, genre, pubYear, publisher,rrPrice, avgRating)
- bookShop (shopNo, shopName, street, city, county)
- orders (orderNo, sNo, oDate, salesRep)
- orderDetails (oNo, bookISBN, quantity)

And this is the query:

```
SELECT 
    title, pubYear, quantity 
FROM 
    book 
INNER JOIN 
    orderDetails ON ISBN = bookisbn
WHERE 
    avgRating = (SELECT MIN(avgRating)
                 FROM orderDetails)
```

I am trying to get the book(s) with the lowest rating however this returns all of the books

Comment: There is no avgRating field in orderDetails?

Comment: There is no field avgRating in orderDetails. It is in book.

Comment: @Zorkolot no, should that way be done first rather than a sub query?

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment please.  It appears you're looking for the min(avgRating) with respect to the different orders.  This is not the same as "get the book(s) with the lowest rating".

Comment: I'll point out that the query does not necessarily give the book with the lowest rating.  The question does not have enough information.  The lowest rating could be determined by Metacritic for example, not by the bookshop.  You are giving the lowest rating for books that have _been ordered_. You have to clarify what granularity is being described here.  Do you want all books regardless whether it was ever ordered in a bookshop, any book that has ever been ordered in a bookshop, or the lowest-rated book for each specific order made in a bookshop?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need below query cause your rating colum is on book table so you might need to change the table name in subquery

```
SELECT title, pubYear, quantity 
FROM book INNER JOIN orderDetails ON ISBN=bookisbn
WHERE avgRating=(SELECT min(avgRating)
                    FROM book )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
SELECT b.title, b.pubYear
FROM book b
WHERE b.avgRating = (SELECT min(b2.avgRating)
                     FROM book b2
                    );
```

Two things.  I removed quantity.  I imagine you want to sum that, but your question doesn't specify and a separate row for each order seems odd.  Second, I added table aliases and qualified column names.  That is what is important.

You think your query is:

```
SELECT b.title, b.pubYear, od.quantity 
FROM book b INNER JOIN 
     orderDetails od
     ON b.ISBN = od.bookisbn
WHERE b.avgRating = (SELECT MIN(od2.avgRating)
                     FROM orderDetails od2
                    )
```

But there is no `avgRating` column in `orderDetails`, so the `WHERE` clause is really:

```
WHERE b.avgRating = (SELECT MIN(b.avgRating)
                     FROM orderDetails od2
                    )
```

Well, you are comparing a column to its outer reference -- no wonder it is always true.

Moral of the story:  *Always* qualify your table names, preferably with meaningful table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.